# Java JDBC: Altering table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, ddl

I wish to make the following alterations to this table:

Add: Column for state (varchar(20))
     column for date (timestamp)

I am unsure how to do so

```
String createTable = "Create table aircraft ("
                        +"aircraftNumber int,"
                        +"airLineCompany varchar(20),"
                        +"departureAirport varchar (20),"
                        +"fuelPercentage int,"
                        +"passengerCount int);";
```

Comment: Execute an `ALTER TABLE` statement. Use `Statement#execute` for DDL statements.

Comment: Can you not just change the string above to include the columns?

Comment: Looks like you need to review your database concepts. This will attempt to create a complete new table, and if the table already exists, the query will fail.

Comment: BTW - `date` is a reserved word in SQL. It isn't a god choice for a column name.

Answer (score 3):

You should `execute` an `alter` statement:

```
Connection conn = ...;
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
s.execute("ALTER TABLE aircraft " + 
          "ADD COLUMN state VARCHAR(20), " + 
          "ADD COLUMN `date` TIMESTAMP");
```

Answer (score 3):

To add columns in a database table, you use the [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) statement:

```
ALTER TABLE aircraft
    ADD COLUMN state VARCHAR(20), 
    ADD COLUMN dateCreated DATETIME
```

<sub>Note that I don't use `date` as name for your field for two reasons: 1) It is a reserved keyword in most database engines, 2) A table field name must be easy to understand for readers, A field named *date* adds no value at all to the current model, which date: date of creation, date of last update, date of aircraft arrival, date of aircraft accident?.</sub>

---

Then, in Java, use [`Statement#execute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-) to perform any DDL statement in JDBC.

To sum it up:

```
String sql = "ALTER TABLE aircraft "
    + "ADD COLUMN state VARCHAR(20), "
    + "ADD COLUMN dateCreated DATETIME";
Connection con = ...
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(sql);
stmt.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Connection conn=new Connection("database path");
String sql="ALTER TABLE Table_name ADD COLUMN Column_name Datatype";

try{
    conn.ExecuteNonSelect(sql);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
```