# Why does Alter Table not work in Java with executeQuery()?

Tags: oracle, java-8, oracle19c

I am trying to alter a table using java with this query. It works in SQL Dev but does not work with executeQuery() in java

```
query = "ALTER TABLE SYSTEM.db_s3 ADD (newColumn CHAR(15));"
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.executeQuery(); --> Error Occured in this line
```

Caused by: Error : 1735, Position : 49, Sql = ALTER TABLE SYSTEM.db_s3 ADD (newColumn CHAR(15)); , OriginalSql = ALTER TABLE SYSTEM.db_s3 ADD (newColumn CHAR(15)); , Error Msg = ORA-01735: Invalid ALTER TABLE Option.

Comment: Can you try changing to  `query = "alter table db_s3 add newcolumn char(15)"` and then run the program like shown in examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481131

Comment: Tried to change the query and used Statement instead of PreparedStatement but still doesn't work.

Comment: is there a different error or is the error the same?

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: you are altering the table,  so should call executeUpdate() instead of executeQuery()

Comment: I used the executeUpdate() but it did not work until I removed the semicolon in the query. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @diane The semicolon is not part of the SQL statement. It's just a terminator used in command line tools, and when writing stored procedures that include multiple SQL statements.